# How do I escape formatting characters in Slack?

Tags: slack, text-formatting, special-characters

Slack uses various characters for its own markdown formatting.

How can I enter a message with those reserved characters escaped?

e.g. Is it possible to send a message exactly like this:

> *I don't want this to be bold*

Comment: I wish I could downvote every answer here.

Comment: Can't you? @RichardSimões

Comment: Need more points!

Comment: This is why slack needs to get off their high-horse and *use a proper markdown engine*.

Comment: NOTE: the only working solution is the comment above my comment of [leclercdumombasin's answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/102398/80167)

Comment: Slack still does not have a way to escape or undo emoji conversion either. *"Sorry, but we don't have a one-time escape for this at the moment. If you'd like you could prevent the conversion by surrounding your text with back-ticks (making a codeblock), but that's not so elegant and probably not what you want."* https://twitter.com/SlackHQ/status/1069536408392671232

Comment: Don't worry guys it will be part of a big "Feature update" one day.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

For the current WYSIWYG editor, hit Ctrl+Z immediately after conversion happened. For example:

```
abc *def* ghi
```

will result in

> abc **def** ghi

On the other hand,

```
abc *def*<CTRL+Z> ghi
```

will result in

> abc *def* ghi

This works for formatting only, not for Slack Emojis.

Comment: Well it took 4 years but we finally have an actual solution from Slack itself.

Comment: Use ⌘Z on a Mac.

Comment: Note this only works when you have "Format messages with markup" switched OFF under preferences -> advanced (so you see a markup toolbar under the text input field). Otherwise, the formatting is only applied *after* you send the message, so you don't have the opportunity to undo it before sending.

Comment: I know this answer is outdated, because these days people have phones.

Comment: This doesn't actually work for example if you want to say:
`Regarding your point #2 I have the following to say ...`
The #2 will turn into a channel link every time. If I type ^Z it simply disappears and I can't find any way to type it. I imagine copy/paste works, but that's a ridiculously horrible solution.

Comment: This also doesn't work if you type up your message externally, such as in a text editor, and then paste it in. It only works if you remember to type ⌘Z in real time as you type - explicitly - in the Slack editor.

Answer (score 40):

**Solution**

Copy and paste the text below and change the word in the asterisks for your own needs:

```
*bold*­
```

It will not be rendered as bold text when you post your Slack message. **Note:** There are hidden characters either side of the asterisks which will prevent Slack from formatting your word(s) between the asterisks.

---

**Explanation**

This is a variation of ShaneB's answer that seems to work better. Instead of *adding* (invisible) space to the asterisk's "attached" side:

```
There is *|no|* spoon            // '|' = vertical tab
```

consider *removing* space on the "detached" side by inserting (invisible) non-space:

```
There is |*no*| spoon            // '|' = e.g. soft hyphen (&shy;, U+00AD)
```

This "embeds" the asterisk and thus renders it inactive. Soft hyphen seems like a good character here.

Comment: Very good. I believe this to be the new best answer which gives the exact desired result. I have edited your post to provide a simple copy/paste solution for people who may not understand how to actually implement it.

Comment: Apparently, you don't need the "shy" char on both sides, just one side is enough.

Comment: |*bold*| is all im getting

Comment: @AdrianBartholomew Instead of the pipe `|` you need to enter the unicode character (U+00AD). On Linux while holding down SHIFT+CTRL press `u` and then the keys `ad`. On Windows while holding down the ALT key type the keys `0173`. More information on unicode input you can find at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_input

Comment: The comment above this one is the only working solution for technicians using Slack!!!

Comment: @sjngm Not true. I have put the working solution at the top of this answer. Read instructions carefully. It works.

Comment: @BadHorsie Well, OK, but you need to understand that the idea of using this feature can't be to copy some text (meaning to always come back to your answer), remove some characters (hopefully not removing the only important one) and writing the actual message. The idea is to know how to write the important character. I don't know in what area or projects you work, but we don't work on same machines all the time (so forget about bookmarks) and sometimes work in a (ridiculously) restrictive network environment.

Answer (score 20):

I just tested and a single back-tick will escape upcoming formatting characters for the rest of the message.

```
`*I don't want this to be bold*`
```

That will be formatted as code

```
`*I don't want this to be bold*
```

That will be formatted  normally but both asterisks will appear instead of making the text bold.

Comment: Interesting. I mean I guess this is something of a "hack" because you are simply making a broken code section, but also this leaves the undesired backtick.

Comment: Yeah, it's not perfect and may be an unsupported hack.

Comment: but what about escaping backtick?

Comment: @GeorgeMauer It's backticks all the way down.

Answer (score 15):

**UPDATE!:** (2017-12-07)

It seems Google has updated the Chrome web browser controls (and possibly others) to show placeholders for many common ASCII control characters, *INCLUDING* the Vertical Tab character!  This change has caused my original Solution below to break, now showing "unknown character" squares or in some cases whitespace breaks, where before it was non-breaking in most use cases (notably Slack!). Not to fear, there is a simple Fix!

**FIX:** Instead of using a Vertical Tab (hex character **0x0B**), NOW use a Form Feed character (hex character **0x0C**)!

**Solution:** Copy the below fixed text to Slack and Edit:

```
There is once again *no* spoon
```

Or use any hex to ascii converter (ie: [ASCII to Hex](http://www.asciitohex.com/)) to convert this:

```
2a 0c 68 61 78 0c 2a
```

Personally I find it's always easiest and more compatible to use an ASCII range solution as opposed to tempting fate with a Unicode solution like in leclercdumombasin's answer.  *HOWEVER,* as far as usability is concerned leclercdumombasin's answer is elegant in that you can simply copy and paste the soft-hyphen and tag any words you want to remain unformatted with only a single hidden character. The primary different between the two is my solution uses characters that will remain hidden if copy/pasted to a simple text-editor, whereas the soft-hyphen solution in my testing converts to a standard looking hyphen in common simple text-editors.

***TL;DR: You now have TWO working solutions for the price of one!***

---

**ORIGINAL POST:**

I had to agree with Richard Simões above, none of these answers actually provided a real solution.  Though they're all correct in one sense, there is no intentionally built method to handle this use case, it would require a hack of some sort.
...And since none of the hacks provided so far are acceptable I grabbed a hotpocket and some Xena tapes and set out to prove my kung-fu was strong.

Result: My kung-fu was strong.

<strike>**Solution:** Use the **Vertical Tab** character.</strike>

As mentioned above you can use a space to sort of detach the asterisks from the word or phrase they're around, like so:

```
These * spaces * will keep it from becoming bold.
```

This in my opinion was the best answer given already, but it still adds the unsightly spaces.  So instead if you were to use the Vertical Tab (VT) it would be enough to separate out the asterisk, without adding the additional space between the asterisks and the word(s) they surround.

Here is the character info, though I am unsure how StackExchange and/or your individual web browser will display this. If it automatically converts it to a space, or something similar refer below to an alternate method:

```
Vertical Tab (between quotes): ""
Decimal: 11
Hex: 0x0b
```

And in a sentence as you would use it on Slack, where I've tested it successfully, regardless of how it works here (just copy/paste into Slack):

```
There is *no* spoon.
```

The easiest way I've found to work with non-printable character hacks like this is to save the sequence in a text file as hex, then whenever I need to use them I can quickly open a new tab, google 'hex to ascii', then copy/paste via any converter.  I also recommend using a text editor that has the option to show whitespace characters. Here is a string in hex to use, just convert to ascii and replace 'hax' with whatever you mean to type:

```
2a0b6861780b2a
```

Comment: My kind of guy. Good job. I mean, crazy, but cool solution. I left this question open for almost a year... this is the only real solution here.

Comment: Interesting. This even works for backquotes - where spaces won't do at all.

Comment: On the latest Slack for Mac, the word didn't get bolded but the final result still has the unsightly spaces between the asterisks and the word they surround.

Comment: @Kelvin - Give it a shot using the newest edits I mentioned above, or try the soft-hyphen method mentioned in the other answer.

Answer (score 7):

There is only one way to achieve what you want: Use a bot to create messages [using the Slack API](https://api.slack.com/docs/formatting). [Here's a page](https://api.slack.com/docs/formatting/builder?msg=%7B%22text%22%3A%22*not%20bold*%22%2C%22username%22%3A%22markdownbot%22%2C%22mrkdwn%22%3Afalse%7D) with an example showing how to do *exactly* what you want.

---

But if you, the human, are typing using the Slack client, as others have said, there's no way to produce a string of text surrounded by asterisks. If you don't want other kinds of formatting applied (like `code`), here are a few compromises that will get you close to what you want:

### spaces (I find this more readable anyway)

`* I don't want this to be bold *`

### leading backslash or underscore

`\*I don't want this to be bold*`

`_*I don't want this to be bold*`

Answer (score 4):

There is a Unicode character, "Combining Grapheme Joiner" (͏Unicode: U+034F, UTF-8: CD 8F) that, if inserted just before one of the special characters in Slack, somehow nerfs Slack's detection of the special characters:

```
I don't want *this* to be bold
             ^- Insert it before this asterisk
```

This <del>trick</del> hack seems to escape the following character, allowing asterisks, tildes, underscores, and (for me most important of all) leading angle brackets to be typed without Slack using them as formatting codes.

I realize that this is a skanky hack: It's relatively easy on a Mac, but I can't speak for my Windows comrades whether this is easy to do or not.

PS: I tried several other Unicode characters, including backspace, thin space, hair space, zero-width space, and so forth, but Slack strips them, at least when they are the 1st character on a line (which makes typing something like `> 9,000!` as a comment impossible in Slack, because it becomes a blockquote).

Comment: This works. This can also be configured in apps like Keyboard Maestro or Typinator on macOS, or AutoHotKey on Windows, making it easy to insert the "Combining Grapheme Joiner" using a short keyboard macro or a hotkey.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe use the Unicode U+066D (٭) character when you mean the * character?

The solution above in which the contributor recommends using the vertical tab character worked for me until I also included markup which used the *..* syntax, at which point it did not.

Comment: Clean and simple solution.

Comment: Also works for the other possible characters one might want to embed, for instance making a line start with >, use › instead.  (U+203A)

Answer (score 2):

To escape a special character, f.e. * or @, type the following characters right before the character that we want to escape:

Keep pressed:

`<ctrl><shift>`

Press and release, one after the other, the following characters:

`u`
`a`
`d`

Release:

`<ctrl><shift>`

For a moment, we will see, underlined:
`uAD`
which will soon become invisible.

Now you can type the special character.

---

This answer is given by @Suboptimal in a comment.

I tried to reply to him but the comments do not allow the needed formatting.

If he will post this answer, I will gladly upvote it and remove this one.

Comment: Ctrl+A now opens unreads so this doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

[Single back ticks will do it, triple back ticks will make it block text](https://slack.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/202288908-Formatting-your-messages) . . . but either will format it as code. As confirmed by this tweet by [Slack](https://twitter.com/SlackHQ/status/664754307980488704).

```
`*I don't want this to be bold*`
```

Comment: I know single backticks format it as code, I am a developer and use them a lot but it's not what I want. It's not the same as escaping a character. I want the message unformatted; code style is formatted.

Comment: Sorry it's not what you want. I failed with a variety of other options \,/<,<! etc. [This tweet](https://twitter.com/slackhq/status/451105387324784640) seems to indicate that it just doesn't exist.

Comment: Actually it's a matter of perspective whether code style is "formatted" and the default style is not. Both are formatted, just with different font families. "Default style" isn't necessarily "unformatted." The question is confusing at best, because the example on the final line shows the text in a monospace format with gray background, which is what Slack does when you use backticks.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to double one of the asterisks.

`*cough**` and `**cough*` both work for me in my testing.

Answer (score 1):

2021 and I still ended up in this thread, on my Windows PC the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> worked, for my phone that didn't so I experimented a bit.

Simplest way I found that works for me on all platforms, add a space after the first asterisk, then after you type the word with the * after it delete the space

So type `I do * not* want bold`, then remove the space before "not" and it will keep the asterisk without making it bold: `I do *not* want bold`

Answer (score 0):

You can enter a Hash with a space, then the text, then use backspace to connect the two.

I.e.

Start with......# SlackIsGreat

Then put the cursor at the 'S" and press backspace.

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP is after, honestly.

Comment: I found this answer via a search for "slack escape character channel hash" and this is a good workaround for me. I realize it doesn't answer the question. Maybe it should be split out into its own question.

Answer (score 0):

I’m adding this comment at this late date as this is the first hit from google for “escaping slack markup”, so hopefully my answer might help someone else save a bit of time. It’s also worth noting that I was looking for a solution that works through the Slack API, rather than the editor too.

Quite frankly, the whole Slack mark-up approach is a bit of a mess. Thankfully, the answer from [leclercdumombasin](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/145202/leclercdumombasin) put me on the right path to a general solution, so a huge thank-you to them!

For each of the characters Slack treats as a special mark-up token `_*~` etc, if you wrap them in a pair of the soft-hyphen characters as described, then they can appear at the beginning, end, or middle of the text, and can be bracketed with whitespace or otherwise.

So for example to escape an `_` within Unicode UTF-8 text the result would be `\xc2\xad_\xc2\xad`

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to get any of the above solutions to work for me. We were sending a dash `-` character without any other text. It was being removed when sending the message to slack programatically. We found that if we send the dash in its unicode representation we found success `"\u002D"`.

tl;dr **Use Unicode Characters**